# Make element id smaller in ASP.NET Webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms

I have a ASP.NET Webform website. Id´s of the elements are often long, like this :

```
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ShowThreads1_repThreads_ctl03_divThreadTitle
```

Most of the id´s is only used at server side so there is really no point in sending id to the client.

Is there anyway to handle this or will I have to manually change my names to somthing like this :

```
ctl00_CPH_ST1_rT_ctl03_dTT
```

This will of course dont say much about the element but the total amount of data sent to client would be reduced a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property introduced in .NET 4.0. You might want `Static` since that will make it just `divThreadTitle`.