# ASP.NET webform and Client element ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms

When using ASP.NET Webform I get element id´s like these :

```
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ShowThreads1_repThreads_ctl03_divThreadTitle
```

I know about the [ASP.NET 4.0 Client ID Feature](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-Client-ID-Feature) but this will only change the name of the element and I do not even use this part?

What I need is to change the id of the elements on the client side to a shorter and better version.

Is this possible? And if so? how?

Comment: I don't see how this is different than your last question  [Make element id smaller in ASP.NET Winforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582119/make-element-id-smaller-in-asp-net-winforms)

Comment: Okay? But Client ID Feture seems only to be changing the name of the element? I need to change the ID itself?

Comment: Huh? `ClientID` as the term implies is the `id` of the element. e.g. `Static` mode: `<input name="ctl00$MainContent$textbox1" type="text" id="textbox1" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a user control dropped on a page, and that page inherits a master page.

If you place ClientIDMode="Static" on the user control as well as your other controls it will shorten the overall name. But why be concerned with the length?

In your code go after the control dynamically by looking at Control.ClientID(). This way you are not hard coding the control name.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the disadvantages of ASP.NET Webforms. It provides a very less control over HTML. In Web Forms many times we are not sure about what html we will get at the end (in your case the id of the control) making integration with JavaScript frameworks like jQuery a difficult task.

Checkout this [Webforms Vs MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528117/WebForms-vs-MVC) to explore more.